# Check if specific a tag is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I do this:

```
var izbor = $('.kategorija_izbor ul a'),
    mgl = $(".mali_oglasi"),
    pretraga = $('.mali_oglas a[role=pretraga]'),
    article = $('.mali_oglasi article'),
    mgl_wrapper = $('.mali_oglasi_wrapper');

(pretraga || izbor).on('click', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('href').split('/'),
        mgl_space = $(this).attr('href').replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    link = mgl_space + ' .mali_oglasi';
    mgl.animate({
        'opacity': 0
    }, 400, function() {
        mgl_wrapper.load(link, function() {
            mgl.animate({
                'opacity': 1
            }, 400);
        });
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});​
```

I need to see if **pretraga** or **izbor** is pressed. This way is not working. Is there a way to make it happen?

Comment: Does this mean you need to check (at some point) which of the two were clicked? Or that you need to bind the `on()` method to both of them?

Comment: do you get any errors? because on my chrome `(pretraga || izbor).on(...)` works

Comment: @haynar: really? I've never seen event binding done that way: cool! =)

Comment: @DavidThomas that was surprise or me too :) but logically it should work because `a || b` returns the variable which is defined if one of them is undefined, otherwise returns the last one

Comment: But doesn't that mean that it will only bind to the first truthy element? And since a jQuery selector will always return an array (even if it's an empty array) the binding will always fail for the second variable? This is untested, and unverified, but...that's how it feels in my head... =/

Comment: I need to check which on is pressed.

Comment: And *where do you need to do this*? Can you insert a comment somewhere that clearly states where the check should be made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `or` operator cannot be used to reference two variable instances.

What you want to do instead is bind the function to multiple `jQuery` objects:

```
$('.kategorija_izbor ul a, .mali_oglas a[role=pretraga]').on('click',
    function(e) {
        var id = $(this).attr('href').split('/'),
            mgl_space = $(this).attr('href').replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
        link = mgl_space + ' .mali_oglasi';
        mgl.animate({
            'opacity': 0
        }, 400, function() {
            mgl_wrapper.load(link, function() {
                mgl.animate({
                    'opacity': 1
                }, 400);
            });
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });​
```

Comment: But those selectors are already stored within variables: *use* the cached selectors: `$(pretraga + ', ' + izbor).on(/*...stuff...*/);`

Comment: Hey David, unfortunately, pretraga/izbor are jQuery objects, not the strings used to represent them.

Comment: That's true, but even so: `pretraga.add (izbor).on (/*...stuff...*/)` should work (and avoid having to re-traverse the DOM to access the same nodes.

Comment: Sorry for hold up. This method is working, but I have a small problem. After the first click, JS stops to work. **mgl_wrapper** is loading elements where **pretraga** is found? How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`$('.mali_oglas a[role=pretraga], .kategorija_izbor ul a').on(...`

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code you can use `isPretraga`  variable inside click function to check if `pretraga` click.

```
var izbor = $('.kategorija_izbor ul a'),
    mgl = $(".mali_oglasi"),
    pretraga = $('.mali_oglas a[role=pretraga]'),
    article = $('.mali_oglasi article'),
    mgl_wrapper = $('.mali_oglasi_wrapper');

$('.mali_oglas a[role=pretraga], .kategorija_izbor ul a').on('click', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('href').split('/'),
        mgl_space = $(this).attr('href').replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    var isPretraga = $(this).attr('role') == 'pretraga';
    link = mgl_space + ' .mali_oglasi';
    mgl.animate({
        'opacity': 0
    }, 400, function() {
        mgl_wrapper.load(link, function() {
            mgl.animate({
                'opacity': 1
            }, 400);
        });
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parentsUntil functions of jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/

So you can see in your click function, which of the two elements are clicked.